# Ubuntu Server 18.04 waiting for Network at startup although the network is ok

Tags: server, wireless, netplan

I have fresh installation of Ubuntu Server 18.04. Until it is all set up and tested, I want it to be connected to both wired and wifi network.

My /etc/netplan directory contains two files:

01-netcfg.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp58s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
      access-points:
        "MyNetworkName":
          password: "MyPassword"
```

50-cloud-init.yaml:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  version: 2
```

When the server boots up, it stays for 2 minutes on this message:

```
A start job is running for Wait for Network to be Configured.
```

While this message is displayed, the server can be pinged over the wired IP, but not over the wifi IP. It can be pinged over the wifi IP right after the 2 minutes of waiting have passed and user prompt is displayed on the connected display.

When I log on, ifconfig shows that both interfaces have initialized fine: both have received their IP addresses from the router, the server is reachable over the network at both IPs.

Here's the output of `networkctl list` command right after boot:

```
$ networkctl list
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged 
  2 eno1             ether              routable    configured
  3 wlp58s0          wlan               routable    configured
```

The wifi router is about 2 meters close, the signal is very strong. Since I don't plan to restart the server too much, the problem of waiting is bearable. But I am afraid this could be a symptom of some network configuration that should be fixed before things get bad.

Comment: After boot, what does 'networkctl list' show?

Comment: @slangasek I added 'networkctl list' output to the post.

Comment: This shows that in the end the network interfaces were both configured via networkd.  I think you should file a bug report (ubuntu-bug systemd) about this issue.

Comment: Is there any way to know what that happened during that waiting time? For some reason, having the wired connection ready was not enough. It had to have both wired and wireless to proceed. And the exact 2 minutes mark feels kind of non-random.

Comment: I'm seeing a very similar problem, but I only have wifi. It stalls for two minutes and then starts up, but at that point I have to run `sudo netplan try` manually to get the wifi to connect. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem, but only if I DO NOT have ethernet via cable.

Answer (score 2):

What if you add

```
  optional: yes
```

to your wifis/wlp58s0 configuration? I had a similar problem, but only when I booted **without** wired ethernet. The content of my `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` (my only file in that dir) was

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: yes
```

When I appended

```
      optional: yes
```

the problem went away. The `man 5 netplan` page states that an `optional` device is not required for booting, and that the default is `false`.