# Issues setting up netplan with 2 NICs, one with ppp

Tags: networking, iptables, netplan, pppoe

I use netplan with 2 NICs, one for the LAN enp0s31f6 and one for the internet enp6s0.

Firstly I can't get systemctl to launch iptables successfully. It says it does in the logs - but when I check, iptables has no rules set up:

```
Apr 27 11:44:31 localhost systemd[1]: Starting iptables...
Apr 27 11:44:31 localhost iptables[1389]: Executing iptables firewall /etc/iptables/iptables.fw
Apr 27 11:44:31 localhost iptables[1389]: Activating firewall
Apr 27 11:44:31 localhost systemd[1]: Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
Apr 27 11:44:31 localhost root: Activating firewall
Apr 27 11:44:31 localhost systemd[1]: Started Authorization Manager.
Apr 27 11:44:31 localhost systemd[1]: Started Accounts Service.
Apr 27 11:44:31 localhost iptables[1389]: Interface ppp0 does not exist
Apr 27 11:44:31 localhost root: Interface ppp0 does not exist
Apr 27 11:44:31 localhost iptables[1389]: Finished executing iptables firewall /etc/iptables/iptables.fw
Apr 27 11:44:31 localhost systemd[1]: Started iptables.
```

There is also a 2 min pause on boot with the message "start job is running Wait for network to be configured", when it should be configured already.

The last problem is the networkctl output - it says one of the NICs is still "configuring" when I'd expect it to say it's done.

Judging by the answer to [Ubuntu Server 18.04 waiting for Network at startup although the network is ok](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035867/ubuntu-server-18-04-waiting-for-network-at-startup-although-the-network-is-ok) , I could just put a sticky plaster over the issue and make the NIC config in my 01-netcfg.yml optional.

I have to start iptables manually - I'm not sure why systemctl claims to run it but fails.

This is the networkctl list:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ networkctl list
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged 
  2 enp6s0           ether              routable    configured
  3 enp0s31f6        ether              routable    configuring
  4 wlp7s0           wlan               off         unmanaged 
  5 ppp0             ppp                routable    unmanaged 

5 links listed.
```

.

```
adam@gondolin:~$ ifconfig -a
enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::10  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fe80::e2d5:5eff:fe62:974c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e0:d5:5e:62:97:4c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9728  bytes 924557 (924.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 59  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 485  bytes 106008 (106.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xf7500000-f7520000  

enp6s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::e2d5:5eff:fe62:974e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e0:d5:5e:62:97:4e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5825  bytes 3847019 (3.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4960  bytes 652504 (652.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xf7200000-f721ffff  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 479  bytes 61492 (61.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 479  bytes 61492 (61.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1472
        inet 81.156.25.53  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 172.16.11.38
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 5504  bytes 3691409 (3.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4710  bytes 534007 (534.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp7s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:e1:8c:75:39:d3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

01-netcfg.yml:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp6s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
    enp0s31f6:
      addresses:
      - fe80::10/128
      - 192.168.0.3/24
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
```

and here's my iptables.service:

```
adam@gondolin:~$ cat /etc/systemd/system/iptables.service

[Unit]
Description=iptables
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
After=ppp.service
Wants=ppp.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/iptables/iptables start
ExecStop=/etc/iptables/iptables stop
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the ppp.service

```
adam@gondolin:~$ cat /etc/systemd/system/ppp.service
[Unit]
Description=PPPoE
#After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pon provider
ExecStop=/usr/bin/poff -a
#Type=notify

[Install]
#WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I notice in your .yaml file that enp0s31f6 has both fixed addresses and dhcp configuration. Can't have it both ways. Your PPP connection has a MTU of 1472... are you sure that's the correct value?

Comment: Stupid me! I had configured it like that because it serves DHCP grants from dhcpd over that NIC. So setting it to dhcp: no has fixed the Wait for... at boot, and the "configuring" status in `networkctl list`

Comment: Your last comment was unclear.

Comment: it's actually entirely possible to have both static and dhcp addresses, but it's apparent that this wasn't what you wanted here.

Comment: @heynnema that error you spotted in the enp0s31f6 config caused the boot `Wait for...` issue, and the `configuring` status for it in `networkctl list`. Thanks. I will check the MTU value for viability later when I've fixed `iptables`

Comment: To make the 2 minute boot delay go away, add "optional: true" to the enp0s31f6 stanza in your .yaml file.

Comment: unnecessary. setting `dhcp: no` was enough.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have defined your ppp service as `Type=oneshot`, other services which depend on it are started immediately, so there is a race between your ppp link being up and iptables running.

I don't offhand know a way to construct a systemd service for ppp that waits for the link to be up before proceeding with dependent services.

Comment: I redefined my ppp service as `Type=forking` but I have discovered that the iptables service is failing even when I run it myself manually, incomprehensibly saying `iptables[1211]: Interface ppp0 does not exist` but that is hard-coded in the iptables script, which succeeds when I run it as `sudo /etc/iptables/iptables start` (my own scripts)

Comment: Actually that error message is mine! This statement at start of my script passes when I run it from the shell: `ip link show ppp0` but it fails when executed by `systemctl`.